# Microsoft.Data.Services.Client connection pooling

Tags: c#, .net, odata

I currently use `Microsoft.Data.Services.Client` to call an internal endpoint providing query capabilities in a .NET Framework 4.7.2 project.

The code performing the query is some variation of this:

```cs
var uri = $"http://myEndpoint/someResource?skip=0&take=100";
// MyDataProvider is an automatically generated class (service reference)
// inheriting from System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext
var result = MyDataProvider.Execute<ProcessOrderWCF>(new Uri(uri), "GET", false)
    ?.ToList();
```

There is nothing inherently wrong with this code, but I'm using it inside a server application, in reusable services, and AFAICT every call to `Execute` is opening a new Http connection to the endpoint for each call.

I'm struggling to understand what is the best way to properly pool/dispose/reuse OData Http connections in a backend-to-backend scenario like mine: under heavy load the simplistic code found in every online example is going to slow the server to a crawl.

Is there any out of the box or recommended solution to address this performance concerns?
I'm interested in anything that can reduce the opening of new Http connections, because that is the largesy slice of the execution time and is the only resource that could be exausted under load.

If no out of the box solutions exists, are there any strategies I can implement? (I'm trying not to implement connection pooling by myself, but I could very well bite the bullet if it turns out to be needed)

Comment: The problem is already solved in .NET Core.  First of all, HTTP is stateless, so every request goes over a "new" connection. The *network* connections aren't handled by OData but HttpClient and HttpClientFactory. if you use HttpClientFactory, you already have pooled socket connections with scheduled recycling

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos, but I'm stuck with .Net Framework, currently... I know, I know, it's a shame...

Comment: 1) That doesn't change the fact that HTTP is stateless and the only thing that can be pooled is the socket connections, which are outside OData Client's control. 2) Even in .NET Framework that's an outdated package supporting outdated OData versions (v3). [Microsoft.OData.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OData.Client) is the supported package, used by the [Visual Studio code generation tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/client/getting-started). Unless you really need to use OData v3, it's better to use the current tools. That's where improvements are made

Comment: In any case on .NET Framework OData uses HttpWebRequest. HTTP connections are pooled by endpoint and can be controlled up to a point through the [ServicePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepoint?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0) and [ServicePointManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager?view=net-6.0) classes.